# Ajax not loading all the javascripts

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

I am trying to load a web page via jQuery AJAX by clicking a menu on the index page (called through a master page). The page is loading fine. Its a shopping cart type thing. Various functions of page are dependent on javascript. Some of  the scripts are workinh fine whereas others are not working fine. Here is my ajax code....

```
$.ajax({
url: "forms.aspx",
success: function (data) {
    $('#formsClick').bind('click', function () {
        $("#index1").load('forms.aspx #forms1');
        $.getScript('../js/libs/modernizr.js');

        //color picker

        $.getScript('../js/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.js', function () {
            var $a = jQuery.noConflict();
            $a(document).ready(function () {

                var preview = $a('.colorpicker-preview')[0].style;
                $a('.colorpicker').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function (ev) {
                    preview.backgroundColor = ev.color.toHex();
                });

            });
        });


        //file upload
        $.getScript('../js/plugins/fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.js');
        $.getScript('../js/plugins/inputmask/bootstrap-inputmask.js');

        //button switch
        $.getScript('../js/plugins/bootstrapSwitch/bootstrapSwitch.js', function () {
            var $b = jQuery.noConflict();
        });


        //tags input
        var myStylesLocation1 = "css/plugins/jquery.tagsinput.css";
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + myStylesLocation1 + '" >').appendTo("head");

        $.getScript('js/plugins/tagsInput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js', function () {
            var $c = jQuery.noConflict();
            $c(document).ready(function () {

                $c('.tagsinput').tagsInput();

            });
        });

        //wysiwyg
        var myStylesLocation = "css/plugins/jquery.jwysiwyg.css";
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + myStylesLocation + '" >').appendTo("head");


        $.getScript('../js/plugins/jWYSIWYG/jquery.wysiwyg.js', function () {
            var $d = jQuery.noConflict();
            $d(document).ready(function () {

                $d('.wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
                    controls: {
                        bold: { visible: true },
                        italic: { visible: true },
                        underline: { visible: true },
                        strikeThrough: { visible: true },

                        justifyLeft: { visible: true },
                        justifyCenter: { visible: true },
                        justifyRight: { visible: true },
                        justifyFull: { visible: true },

                        indent: { visible: true },
                        outdent: { visible: true },

                        subscript: { visible: true },
                        superscript: { visible: true },

                        undo: { visible: true },
                        redo: { visible: true },

                        insertOrderedList: { visible: true },
                        insertUnorderedList: { visible: true },
                        insertHorizontalRule: { visible: true },

                        cut: { visible: true },
                        copy: { visible: true },
                        paste: { visible: true }
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            if ($d("#click-inform:checked").length > 0) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                alert("You have clicked jWysiwyg content!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        });



        //editor
        var myStylesLocation = "css/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css";
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + myStylesLocation + '" >').appendTo("head");

        $.getScript('../js/plugins/wysihtml5/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js');
        $.getScript('../js/plugins/wysihtml5/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js', function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $e = jQuery.noConflict();
                // Note, we are adding .btn-alt to toolbar template directly in bootstrap-wysihtml5.js for better readability
                $e('.wysihtml5').wysihtml5();

            });
        });

        //datepicker
        $.getScript('js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js', function () {
            var $f = jQuery.noConflict();
            $f(document).ready(function () {

                $f('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    "autoclose": true
                });

            });
        });

        //daterange picker
        var myStylesLocations = "css/plugins/daterangepicker.css";
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + myStylesLocations + '" >').appendTo("head");

        $.getScript('js/plugins/dateRangePicker/date.js');
        $.getScript('js/plugins/dateRangePicker/daterangepicker.js', function () {
            var $g = jQuery.noConflict();
            $g(document).ready(function () {

                $g('#demoDaterangePicker').daterangepicker();

            });
        });

        //timepicker

        $.getScript('js/plugins/bootstrapTimePicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js', function () {
            var $h = jQuery.noConflict();

            $h(document).ready(function () {

                $h('#demoTimepicker').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 5,
                    showInputs: false,
                    disableFocus: true
                });

            });
        });

        //validation
        $.getScript('js/plugins/bootstrapValidation/jqBootstrapValidation.min.js', function () {
            var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
            $i(document).ready(function () {

                $("#demoValidation input").jqBootstrapValidation({
                    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

            });
        });



        $.getScript('js/plugins/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js', function () {
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j(document).ready(function () {

                $j('.custom-checkbox input, .custom-radio input').prettyCheckable();

            });
        });



    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Are the relative URL correct?

I'm asking because I see some getScript are like this `$.getScript('../js/etc.'` and others like this: `$.getScript('js/etc.'`.

I don't know if that's THE problem but it is probably A problem.

Anyway, if you use Chrome developer tools (ctrl+shift+i) in the "console" tab you should be able to understand the problem.